# How to visualise overlapping lines and attribute color based on frequency

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics, linked-data

I would like to visualize the datapoints, or lines in this case, that are overlapping, and assign 1) a color based on how many overlapping lines there are.

Data is an import of a shapefile where i connected simple points, and the data has many inputs per line. Each line has , in many cases, "exists" multiple times.
[image: each line overlapping and assign to nice colorramp based on how many times that particular line exist (from a to b)]
In blender, everytime I import the points, or in this case the lines, even though the geonodes index matches my number of datapoints, it shows as one line or point in the viewport. I haven't figured out how to show multiple datapoints that stack on top of eachother in a way where it is visible there are differences in frequence between the existence of datapoints on that xyz (lines in this case).

While what I want is:

- figure out how i can show a color for lines that overlap a lot, for instance based on a opacity level and a nice colorramp.
- (optional) play with the named attribute country name to make multiple colorramps differ based on that named attribute.

But the first question is the thing i'm primarily stuck on!

[image]